# How can Ionic recognize the URL when input and send the email with password to login based on the URL

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have created a place for inputting the URL into the login form page with the attribute

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label floating>Company URL</ion-label>
<ion-input type="url" value="" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
<ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" formControlName="email" value="" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>


<ion-item>
<ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
<ion-input type="password" formControlName="password" value="" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

I will have a company URL to input the URL of my company, for example abc.com/login is my company URL. I will send my cresdential to the company URL and login through it. Is there anyway that I can login through the company URL and send my cresdential and login using inputted URL.

This is my loginAuth.ts

```
urlLogin = api+"/login";

login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post(this.urlLogin,{
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
      "url" : url
    })
  }
```

This is the loginAuth.ts and I want to replace the urlLogin to the URL from company URL. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you can use [(ngModel)] with your ion-input like this. And also use [(ngModel)] for other inputs too. It is much easier. Don't forget to put name attribute for your inputs when using [(ngModel)]

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label floating>Company URL</ion-label>
<ion-input type="url" name="companyURL" [(ngModel)]="companyURL" value="" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
<ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" value="" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>


<ion-item>
<ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
<ion-input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" value="" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

And then in your .ts file define these variables globally

```
public companyURL: string = ""
public email: string = ""
public password: string = ""
```

Then use them in your login()

```
login() {
    return this.http.post(this.companyURL + '/login',{
      "email": email,
      "password": password
    })
}
```

I guess this is what you are looking for

Comment: I think i will try this way. This flow like you said is suitable with my current situation.